# OdbcDataAdapter Fill throws OverflowException Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: c#, ado.net

I try to retrieve data from db2 using OdbcDataAdapter and this code works perfectly in my old machine (Windows 7 32 bit, VS2010)

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string sql, string connstr)
{
    using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(connstr))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I start a new project in my new machine (Windows 64 bit, VS2013) using the same code. I got exception when executing `adapter.Fill(ds)`

```
System.OverflowException
Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

I have no clue because the same code and sql query works on my old machine. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

StackTrace

```
 at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetSqlType(Int32 i)
 at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetFieldType(Int32 i)
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.SetupSchemaWithoutKeyInfo(MissingMappingAction mappingAction, MissingSchemaAction schemaAction, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object chapterValue)
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping..ctor(DataAdapter adapter, DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Boolean keyInfo, SchemaType schemaType, String sourceTableName, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
 at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillMappingInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 schemaCount, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
 at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillMapping(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 schemaCount, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
 at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
 at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
 at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
```

Comment: Recently I've run into the same problem. Might it be that you are running the 32 bit ODBC driver from 64 bit? Is it on DB2/400 using the iSeries adapter?

Comment: @GuidoLeenders Yes, it's DB2/400

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue with my project

On my 64Bit system I'd get the same error, query ran fine in SQL, no data out of bounds.

Only solution I found so far was to **build the application as a 32 bit application** (this solved the error for me)

Comment: Your workaround WFM - using typed DataSets so all the code is auto-generated. Query is literally SELECT * FROM someTable. DataSet designer "Preview Data" function works fine, but when deployed app is run or debugged, OverflowException.. Changing build to target x86 platform and the error went away. Guessing it's to do with MySQL ODBC driver "bitness" - VS is 32bits/designer runs in 32bits but app runs in 64 unless forced to x86

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same or similar problem. I was relatively positive it wasn't related to to the 32 VS 64 bit issue, despite that being the solution that came up with all my searches.

As it turned out, at least in my instance, that wasn't what caused it.

The database (MYSQL) that my odbc adaptor was reading from had been recently modified to include a new column that was set up with the 'TINYINT' type, which I gather was supposed to be the equivalent of a boolean. This datatype is what was causing the exception.

Upon switching the datatype of that column in the database to 'INT' instead of 'TINYINT' the exception was relieved and the site worked normally.

I thought I would post this reply as another avenue for anyone else that happened to run into this issue due to a similar change.